# Return first date where corresponding value is greater than 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a set of data as below.  Note that not all dates are represented.
[image]

I'm looking for an Excel 365 formula that when passed a sample date will return a date from within the table that is earlier or equal to the sample date and the corresponding value is the first value that is greater than 0.

- So for the 1st to the 8th February the formula will return 01-Feb-21
  as that's the first date on the table.
- For the 10th to the 16th it will return the 10th as that's the first date where the value
  increased above 0.
- For the 17th to the end of the table it will return 17th.

One of my attempts:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[Date]<=D2),--(Table1[Value]>0),Table1[Date])` - for 2nd Feb the first two dates are true, as are the first two numbers so it adds the dates together and returns 08-Mar-42.
`D2` in the above formula contains a date that is within the bounds of 01-Feb to 25-Feb.

I've tried working with `=MIN(IF((Table1[Date]<=D2)*(Table1[Value]>0),Table1[Date],"-"))` which returns 1st Feb.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem.

To help me figure it out, I framed it in these words:

> we are looking to return the minimum of all dates before or on the
> parameter date, between the maximum date where the value is zero and
> the date of the parameter

The part after the comma is the tricky part, I think, because dates later in the series could have more than one row with a zero before them.

Anyway, I think this will do the trick:

```
=MIN(FILTER(Table1[Date],Table1[Date]>IFERROR(MAX(FILTER(Table1[Date],(Table1[Value]=0)*(Table1[Date]<=Table1[@Date]))),MIN(Table1[Date])-1)))
```

To break it apart, we first want to get a list of dates before the parameter date that have a zero in the value. We do that with this:

```
=FILTER(Table1[Date],(Table1[Value]=0)*(Table1[Date]<=Table1[@Date]))
```

But from that list, we only want the most recent row with a zero, so we use MAX as well:

```
=MAX(FILTER(Table1[Date],(Table1[Value]=0)*(Table1[Date]<=Table1[@Date])))
```

The problem here is that for the first set of rows (before Feb 8), there is no  row with a smaller date with a zero, so it returns the #CALC! error:

[image]

To deal with that, we wrap it in IFERROR such that if the formula above returns an error, we make it return the MIN of the whole series of dates instead:

```
=IFERROR(MAX(FILTER(Table1[Date],(Table1[Value]=0)*(Table1[Date]<=Table1[@Date]))),MIN(Table1[Date]))
```

[image]

What we're trying to get here is the maximum date of the collection of (zero-row dates) and (the largest date before the first date in the table). This latter point means we need to subtract 1 from the second parameter of the IFERROR such that it doesn't return Feb 1, which is the first date with a value, but it returns the day before that:

```
=IFERROR(MAX(FILTER(Table1[Date],(Table1[Value]=0)*(Table1[Date]<=Table1[@Date]))),MIN(Table1[Date])-1)
```

[image]

OK, this is good. Now we have for each row the date of the most recent zero-row (or a date before the first date in the table).

So we need to filter the dates after *that* date but before or on the parameter date, then get the minimum value of the range of the results.

This formula would do that:

```
=FILTER(Table1[Date],Table1[Date]>IFERROR(MAX(FILTER(Table1[Date],(Table1[Value]=0)*(Table1[Date]<=Table1[@Date]))),MIN(Table1[Date])-1))
```

Then to get the smallest of that list of dates, you just wrap the whole thing in MIN, as shown at the top of my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  That does the trick.  I'm taking it in preference to @JvdV answer purely on the volatility of his/her answer.  One small change I made was to change the `<=` to just `<` so the 0 values display the date from the previous 0 rather than the following date (as in "today the value is 0, it was last raised above 0 a few days ago", rather than "today the value is 0 and it will rise above 0 tomorrow").

Comment: One small thing I've noticed though - if the value is 0 for two days in a row the second day returns the current date rather than the same as the previous row.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest a filter function within `vlookup` to get what you want, for example:

`=VLOOKUP(DATEVALUE("02/16/2021"),FILTER(A2:B18,B2:B18>0),2,true)`

Answer (score 0):

Though volatile, you could try `OFFSET()` here:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=IF(OFFSET([@Val],-1,0)=0,[@Date],IF([@Val]=0,OFFSET([@Date],-1,2),MIN([@Date],OFFSET([@Date],-1,2))))
```